# Implementation Differences between SGD Tensorflow and PyTorch SGD

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0

Some issues I am getting while training with identical code ported from Pytorch to TF2.

- Model.fit converges in a completely different manner than Gradient Tape. (And more similar to Pytorch)
- tf.keras.optimizers.SGD converges very different than pytorch SGD. (e.g. a LR of 0.1 for tf is unstable at training while the same starting LR for Pytorch is used in many SOTA implementations)

I couldn't come up with a toy example to demonstrate the issue without needing many epochs to train and can be demonstrated in a few lines of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it the case for the same models, exactly same weights, exactly the same seeds and exactly same data in the same order? Given that (and no other regularization) results should be identical (or almost the same).

Comment: Actually I think what I observe could be a direct cause of: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/44917

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is quite old, but having just run into the same problem porting a pytorch implementation to keras 3 I've identified the following differences:

### Weight Decay

keras implements weight decay correctly. Pytorch implements L2 regularization. Without momentum, these are equivalent, but with momentum the regularization loss contributes to momentum.

### Initialization

Pytorch initializes momentum values as the initial gradient, while keras initializes with all zeros.

### Learning rate multiplication

Keras scales the gradient updates by the learning rate, while pytorch scales the final momentum by the learning rate before doing the update (there's also a factor of -1 difference between each's internal variables, but this shouldn't affect anything). For uniform learning rates these are equivalent, but for dynamic learning rates this could affect things.

Some of this is now documented in the note in [pytorch's documentation for SGD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.SGD.html#torch.optim.SGD).